# SELECT UNION from multiple tables with same schema in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, union

I want to `SELECT` (combine) records from multiple tables with the same schema. This is the query that I use:

```
SELECT visitor_name, in_time, out_time, blacklist FROM visitor_archive_2012 UNION 
SELECT visitor_name, in_time, out_time, blacklist FROM visitor_archive_2013 UNION 
SELECT visitor_name, in_time, out_time, blacklist FROM visitor_archive_2014 UNION 
SELECT visitor_name, in_time, out_time, blacklist FROM visitor_archive_2015
```

I am quite certain there is a less redundant and verbose way to write this query. The schema for each of the table is exactly the same. This is in MySQL 5.6

Comment: Unless its select * from table, I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: One improvement you can probably make is using `UNION ALL` (I suppose there are no duplicate rows in these tables). It's probably going to improve performance a lot.

Comment: @agenovese you mean `SELECT * FROM visitor_archive_2012 UNION SELECT * FROM visitor_archive_2013 UNION SELECT * FROM visitor_archive_2014` ?

Comment: NB difference between UNION and UNION ALL and the likely performance implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a less redundant/verbose way -- `PARTITION` a single table by year.  Then a single `SELECT` will do the job.

But, that may not even be wise.  What queries benefit from your splitting it into multiple tables?

Comment: No good reason to split into multiple tables; it is a legacy application with the database designed by an inexperienced programmer

Answer (score 1):

As @Rick says, I would question first why you need to have separate tables but assuming this is out of your control, if this is a regular query, may be simplest to create a view. Possibly if these are MyISAM tables you could consider a Merge table as well.